# Symfony and AWS installation issue

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, amazon-web-services

I tried to install the Symfony on AWS, but ti have one problem. It doesn't work.

I setup the the EC2 as following
Amazon Linux AMI 2017.03.0 (HVM), SSD Volume Type
run the next shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd24 php56 mysql56-server php56-mysqlnd
service httpd start
chkconfig httpd on
service mysqld start
chkconfig mysqld on
sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
sudo yum install -y phpMyAdmin
cd /var/www/html
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
sudo curl -LsS https://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

Later I run the "mysql_secure_installation" to setup the mySQL

Every thing was fine and I can see the folders.

the problem is I still can see the /web/ folder files.

I tried to play with the .htaccess without any progress. 
I tried to change the "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf" file to be  `AllowOverride All`

Still no success. any way or any step I missed

Comment: From your script snippet I read that you installed the symfony-installer. That is a CLI-tool for setting up a new project, e.g. by running `symfony new my-project`. That project should then be deployed to your AWS-instance into your web accessible-folder, e.g. `var/www/` (also then you have to probably change the web root as it seems to be `/var/www/html`).

Comment: I have done that. http://54.236.242.3/test/

Comment: It looks like apache is not configured correctly. Can you post the contents of the changes you made to `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`?

Comment: I tried 2 things (None of them work 
First change AllowOverride to All
 <Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
And the other one was 

<Directory "/var/www/html/test/web">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]